# How to make Nth column to fill empty width in table

Tags: html, css

See this example:
[image]

The table width is set to 100%, but I want the `Subject` column to fill the empty width rather than `Start time` column or any other (which should be minimal width+padding)

CSS:

```
    table, th {
      border:1px solid black;
      text-align:left;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      table-layout: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 4px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    th {
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

Live sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/436az2o5/)

Comment: add `width: 100%;` to only the th with the subject, not all of them

Comment: Do exactly what @TemaniAfif said. You can do this with a class or id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will help you

```css
body {
        font-family: Calibri;
}
table, th {
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align:left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: auto;
        
}
table th:nth-child(3){width: 100%;}
td {
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align:left;
}
a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
}
td, th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 4px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
th {
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #3399ff;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table><thead><tr><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Subject</th><th>Response</th></tr></thead><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>
                    fill width
                </td>
                <td>
                    something
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set width `auto` to `th` `td` and `table` to `100%`

```
td, th {
      width: auto;
    }

table {
        width: 100%;
}
```

and using `th:nth-last-child(3)` set `subject` width to `100%`

Answer (score 1):

```
table, th 
{ border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto; 
  width 100%; 
} 
td, th 
{ border: 1px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 4px; 
  padding-right: 30px; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
} 
th 
{ padding-top: 8px; 
  padding-bottom: 8px; 
  text-align: left; 
}
```

**text-align :left - >Shift text left **

Comment: Thank you for replying but I didn't understand your attention..

Answer (score 0):

Don't give `100%` globally to all `th`. Give it to needed `th` as below.

```css
body {
        font-family: Calibri;
}
table, th {
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align:left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: auto;
}
td {
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align:left;
}
a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
}
td, th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 4px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
th {
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #3399ff;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th width="100%">Subject</th>
            <th>Response</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>00:00</td>
            <td>00:00</td>
            <td>
                fill width
            </td>
            <td>
                something
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```